# i want to receive string from python server

Tags: python, android, sockets

I'm making an application using android and Python.
android is client
python is server
i send image file to python and want to receive string from server
but No strings are coming from the server.
socketIn.readLine() This part does not work.

```
try { // 소켓을 생성하고 입출력 스트립을 소켓에 연결
            clientSocket = Socket(ip , port)
            Log.d("Socket>>>>>>", "ip and port open Success!!!!!")
            //val inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream()
            val tempfile = file

            try{
                socketIn = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))
                //socketOut = PrintWriter(BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),true)
                dis = DataInputStream(FileInputStream(tempfile))
                dos = DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream())
                val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                var read_length : Int = 0

                do {
                    read_length = dis.read(buf)
                    if(read_length == -1)
                        break
                    dos.write(buf)
                    dos.flush()
                } while(read_length > 0)

                var line : String?
                var StringBuilder = StringBuilder()


                do {
                   line = socketIn.readLine()

                   if(line == null)
                       break
                   StringBuilder.append(line)
                }while(line != null)

                onApiResult(line)

            } catch (e : Exception){
                Log.d("error", "${e}")
                onApiFailed()
            } finally {
                clientSocket.close()
            }
```

this is my android client code. client send the image to python server using tcp.
The image is sent well but the string does not come.
There is an error here line = socketIn.readLine()
please tell me how to fix it

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 8000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('123.234.345.456', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is ready to receive')
msg = "hi"
while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    img_file = open('hi.jpg', "wb")

    while True:
        sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        data = sentence
        img_file.write(sentence)
        if sentence:
            print("recving IMg....")
            print(sentence)
            sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            img_file.write(sentence)

        else:
            print('Done')
            img_file.close()
            break

    connectionSocket.sendall(bytes(msg, 'UTF-8'))


connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: If you use readLine() the server should send a line which it does not now. Change msg = "hi" to msg = "hi\n".

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess -- you are sending binary data, but your client code uses java Reader/Writer classes (dedicated to reading text-like data).  Use Streams, instead of Reader/Writer.  There is no notion of 'endOfLine' when reading binary data.  Also note, that client call to 'readLine()' assumes client platform dependent end-of-line, whatever it may be.  If server and client platform differ, it will never work.